# series involving zeros of analytic functions

Tags: complex-analysis

Question: Let $D$ denote the open unit ball. Let $f \colon D \to \mathbb{C}$ be a bounded analytic function so that $f(0) \neq 0$. Suppose $\{a_k\} \subset D$ is a sequence pairwise distinct complex numbers in $D$ and $f(a_k) = 0$ for all $k$. Show that the series $\sum \ln |a_k|$ converges.

My attempt: For each $N$, consider the Blaschke product $B_N(z) := \prod_{k=1}^N \frac{a_k - z}{1 - \overline{a_k} z}$. Let $M > 0$ be so that $\sup_{z\in D}|f(z)| < M$ then the map $F(z) = \frac{1}{M} f$ is a holomorphic function from $D \to D$. In fact, the function $F_N \colon D \to D$ defined by $F_N(z) = \frac{F(z)}{B_N(z)}$ can be extended to be a holomorphic function on $D$. So, by maximum modulus principle, we have $|B_N(z)| \geq |f(z)|$ for all $z \in D$ and setting $z =0$ we have $|\prod a_k| \geq |f(0)|$.

However, I am only able to obtain a lower bound as I not sure how to define the map $\frac{\prod_{k=1}^\infty \frac{a_k - z}{1 - \overline{a_k} z}}{F(z)}$ on $D$, whether it is holomorphic or not. Any hints are appreciated.

Comment: Try and do the same thing but in a disc of radius $r<1$ where there are only finitely many zeroes (essentially the result here follows from Jensen's theorem and the above plus the refinement noted are how Jensen is proved)

Comment: @MartinR Thank you. I forgot to upvote your answer previously. I have proven the statement via the equivalence $\sum \ln |a_k| \in \mathbb{R} \iff \sum (1 - |a_k|) \in \mathbb{R}$, provided $|a_k| < 1$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All terms in $\sum \ln |a_k|$ are negative, so the series converges exactly if the partial sums are bounded below. And that is true because for each $N$
$$
 \sum_{k=1}^N \ln |a_k| = \log \left(\prod_{k=1}^N |a_k| \right) \ge \log\left( \frac 1M |f(0)| \right) \, .
$$